# Invalidation scheme for high level data models that is based on low level data

Tags: modeling

There is a saying about the most challenging aspects of software development is "Cache invalidation and naming things". This question is about the former of the two. Though the nature of the problem seems something that should be common, I did not find much reading on google.

I'm working on an editor for production plants, but I think the problem I'm addressing is easier to understand if I try to explain it in terms of a circuit board.

Imagine that you have a circuit board data model Your data consists basically of a list of components, their properties and their connections.

You have a lot of ways to identify various constructs on the circuit board that describe what you have produced (regulator loops, failsafe switchover, duty/standby configuration). The exact constructs aren't important, but they belong to different object models that isolate certain aspects of the underlying circuit boards.

As long as this is a static representation of the underlying circuit board we don't have any problems. The high level emergent constructs are somewhat costly to calculate, but no problem since it only happens once.

Now, I need to expand this into a dynamic editor. I want to offer operations on the higher level model whilst the data is still a list of the individual components.
Eg. an existing loop shall be modified with eg a fuse.
Naturally, this would be solved by the high level model identifying the correct spot for the fuse in its circuitry and adding the component as well as connections in the underlying data base.

So, the high level model offers a high level configuration change that is realized by a series of low level configuration changes.

This is, again, no problem as long as the underlying data model is only affected by the single high level model.

But, what I want to do is to **Dynamically** update the high level model from changes in the low level model so that the high level model does not care **how** the fuse was added or by whom. It could be:

- From its own utility function
- Direct operation into the low level data.
- Another instance of the same high level model.
- Another high level model.

Now, the system is already in a layered architecture such that the low level data has a data  access layer that can be used for push notifications.

I don't know what exact google phrase would give relevant results, so I'm asking the question here if anybody know of academia, blogs, solutions or something relevant to this.

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually, there are two separate steps:

1. Invalidation
2. Recomputation/revalidation

For the first step, your high level model must know which changes in the low level model can cause it to become invalid, and it needs to listen to these events. For example, if a high level construct "loop" depends on its constituent low-level components being present and connected, each change that either removes a component or disconnects it would invalidate the loop.

Once a high level construct has been invalidated, you may either try to see whether it can be revalidated given the current state of the low level model, or you just throw it away. You will always need mechanisms to create high level constructs out of thin air when the low level model changes somehow, for example when components are connected a loop may appear. Whether this process can be helped by keeping invalidated high level constructs around depends on your specific cases.

As an example of a system that works like this, look at syntax coloring editors in IDEs such as VS Code (just as an example since I'm currently using it somewhat regularly). The high level constructs (syntactic entities of the programming language) are detected by parsing the input, and code is appropriately colored. When I change some text, the syntax may become invalid. The editor could remove all coloring, but it normally keeps the assigned colors and tries to adapt to the new parse quickly when I'm done with my change.

I haven't yet looked at the code which does this in a syntax driven editor, so I can't say whether it would be usable as an inspiration for a system that would be applicable to your specific problem, but the general approach should be comparable.

Comment: Yes, an IDE is a good example of constructs that can be effected either by direct change or eg through a dependency. I shall see if I draw inspiration from that directly or it will help me uncover some theory on the subject. 
It is interesting though because of the historical way c++ compilers worked by creating a middle step that allowed reuse of compiled units and then only link step would be required. Maybe that will help me both establish units of reuse to both make invalidation easier and reuse unaffected segments.